# How to find out given equation represent a family of coaxial Circles?

Tags: geometry, circles

Equation is

$$x^2+ y^2-2ax [(1+k^2)/(1-k^2)]+ a^2 =0$$

How to know this equation represents a family of coaxal circles?

If we find some point in the procedure, plz tell the right way of determining it.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to complete the square for a quadratic?

Comment: See my answer to a similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2247852/how-do-find-out-circles-represent-a-family-of-coaxial-circles-from-their-equatio/2248056#2248056

Comment: @paul yes I know

Comment: Which is the parameter of the family, $a$ or $k$?

Comment: I think you forgot a parenthesis there, in $k/(1-k^2)$.

Comment: I guess the parameter is the whole coefficient term of -2x

Comment: @aretino I am not able to understand the meaning of -passing from same couple of points. And how to determine the points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all let me set $t=(1+k^2)/(1-k^2)$ (notice that $|t|\ge1$), so that your equation becomes:
$$
x^2+y^2-2atx+a^2=0.
$$
This represents a real circle for every value of $a$ and for $|t|\ge1$, so we have a family of circles, with centers $(at,0)$ and radii $|a|\sqrt{t^2-1}$.

Suppose $a$ has a fixed value (e.g. $a=1$): you can check that for all values of $t$, the imaginary points $P=(0,ia)$ and $Q=(0,-ia)$ belong to the circle. We then say that all the circles we get for different values of $t$ (with $a$ fixed) pass through the same couple of points ($P$ and $Q$) and thus form a family of coaxial circles.

To find $P$ and $Q$, notice that they are a solution of the circle equation for all values of $t$: it follows that they are also a solution of the equation obtained by differentiating the circle equation with respect to $t$:
$$
-2ax=0,
\quad\hbox{whence:}\quad
x=0.
$$
Substituting that into the circle equation we get $y=\pm ia$.

Comment: What is we call parameter in above equation? How did you find point?

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks.what you were saying about parameter. Plz tell.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to know about the parameter: could you explain more clearly?

Comment: Above you are asking that which is the parameter of family a or k. Could you tell me about what parameter of family means ?

Comment: To have a family of coaxial circles, $a$ has to be fixed. This family is then parameterized by $t$ (or $k$) alone. That's what I meant when asking for "the parameter of the family": it is $t$ (or $k$) and not $a$.

Comment: Ok thanks so much. You helped a lot